# Remove space below footer on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, footer

Is there any way to remove the space below the footer here: https://starplatforms.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: Using FF55 on Linux, there is no space below the footer. Did you check the CSS for any margins on the footer or paddings on the container or body?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, questions such as this do not meet the guidelines for the site. You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting, and questions should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your site contains an iframe at the bottom (something with google ads I think). Move it somewhere else if you still need it, or remove/hide it.

Comment: I have checked and it was my Google remarketing tag, which I was using inside the StoreYa plugin. I have now disabled the plugin and inserted the tracking code within my theme custom css. Thanks for the help